# Page redirection without refreshing pages

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6

I try to build an SPA with(laravel&vuejs).But when i use the class "nav-item has-treeview"  to list my projects or anything else i can't acess to project page without refreshing pages .Any help??.
this is my home.blade.php:

```
   <li class="nav-item has-treeview ">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
         <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tasks"></i>
         <p>
           Gantt
           <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
         </p>
       </a>

       @foreach ($projet   as $project)


       <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
         <li class="nav-item">
           <router-link :to="`/gantt/{{$project->id}}`" class="nav-link ">
             <i class="far fas fa-circle"  style="color:#05dfd7"></i>
             <p>Gantt :{{ $project->name }} </p>
           </router-link>
         </li>

       </ul>

       @endforeach
       </li>
```

and this my app.js(routes):

```
{path: '/gantt/:id' , component: gantt},
```

Comment: How do you want to show the project data? You show us a list of your projects, but not how you want to present a project. If you can show us how you want to show the project-data, we can give you a better example/solution to your issue. My first impression is that you should use `v-for` in first `ul` in stead of `@foreach`, this way you can use each project dynamically since you are utilizing vue and not blade.

Comment: @RobBiermann i think the issue is not how i list the project and i think  can't use v-for because i want to show the gantt project list in home.blade.php because i have other example without the "nav-item has-treeview" and it work